# How can I take the content of dynamic fields when click on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function the add dynamically title and text fields.

Code: [jdfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8p31sm2/1/)

When I click on "add new" button I would like that those info (title and text) was saved into an array of object "info":

```
function info(title, text){
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
}

var listInfo = [];
```

After that, "add new" button shows a new field to complete. An so on.

I don't know how can I manage the id of every field. 
Take the values is simple, just only use `$("#id").val()`. But the id must be different!

Some ideas? And if I decide to modify the text of field just inserted? How can I overwrite that specific element of the array? With `.keypress()` function? Ok, but remains the id problem..

Comment: You could add variable to your code like var `idNo = 0` on initialization and increase it on each "Add new" click and then build new ids like: `var newId= idNo+'somestring'`

Comment: @SzybkiSasza
Ok, but if I would take the info of one field? How can I get that same id?

Comment: @DavideFruci I think what you're looking for is this. https://jsfiddle.net/b8p31sm2/6/ check the console for the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add randomy number to **id** should work fine, find you example here with random id :

```
var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - x));
```

[Your exemple worked with random id](https://jsfiddle.net/b8p31sm2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you have `id="titleInfo"` but the ID must be unique and start with a letter.  One suggestion would be to use a class and not an ID or append the ID with a number (index of the added instance for example)  In this case I would simply get the length of the elements by a class like your "form-group" with:

`id="titleInfo' + $('.form-group').length + '"` or some such

Example of your fiddle with the update:
https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/b8p31sm2/3/